# ASW-SDK does not return mutliple images

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, multer, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a node mutler and aws-sdk image upload project to aws s3, I am facing issues with getting the images back.
s3.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
// function that uploads file to s3
function uploadFile(file){
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
    const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Body: fileStream,
        Key: file.originalname
    };
    return s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
}

// function downloads file from s3
function getFileStream(fileKey){
    const downloadedParams = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileKey
    };
    return s3.getObject(downloadedParams).createReadStream();
    // return s3.getObject(downloadedParams);
}
```

Here is the controller.js

```
exports.getUserImages = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const userID = req.params.userId;
        const images = await Gallery.find({userID});
        if (! images) {
            res.status(400).json({message: 'No images found'});
            return;
        }
        console.log(images);
        // find show all those images
        for (const image of images){
            const readStream = getFileStream(image.key);
            readStream.pipe(res);
        }
   
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({message: e.message});
    }
};
```

This works when I use findOne and it displays the image, but when I try to get all the images it does not work, it is just a blank screen. I have the names of the images as Key in my local database and my asw s3 bucket is public I only want to access the image not download.

mongodb

```
key:"PIC.jpeg"
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're doing. do `Gallery.find({userID})` returns an array of key, which you use it to loop and pipe your stream?

I'm suspecting that the `readStream` kept getting piped by different image.

You can try `s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response`

Comment: ok I will try this